# Strange behavior from strip_tags PHP

Tags: php, html, strip-tags

I have some HTML as a string in PHP that I've used `$html_str= html_entity_decode()` on. So a sample of the HTML now looks like this:

```
echo $html_str; // <p>This is <span class='some_class'>some</span> text, yeah!<br>Hello world.</p>
```

When I do this:

```
$html_str= strip_tags($html_str, '<p>');
echo $html_str; // This is some text, yeah!Hello world.
```

it strips all tags including the `<p>` tags.

But if I do:

```
$html_str= strip_tags($html_str, '<br>');
echo $html_str; // <p>This is some text, yeah!<br>Hello world.</p>
```

it strips the `<span>` tags and leaves the `<br>` and the `<p>`.

What's going on here?

Comment: if you do `var_dump($html_str);` after the `strip_tags()`, do the `<p>` tags still show up?

Comment: @iam-decoder yes, they do still show up.

Comment: @iam-decoder Thanks for helping. What's your thinking on that?

Comment: Can't recreate it, <p> tags should be shown in html source, please re-check it....

Comment: @mark I was thinking that in some way your server (or php) was configured such that when you `echo`d a plain text node, it was automagically wrapped in `<p>` tags

Answer (score 0):

The second argument `$allowable_tags` says which tags are allowed:

```
<?php

$html_str = "<p>This is <span class='some_class'>some</span> text, yeah!<br>Hello world.</p>";

echo strip_tags($html_str, '<p>') . "\n";

echo strip_tags($html_str, '<br>') . "\n";
```

Output is:

```
<p>This is some text, yeah!Hello world.</p>
This is some text, yeah!<br>Hello world.
```

as expected.

http://ideone.com/5R3VvZ

The most likely explanation to me is that you don't really have `<br>` in your string but something else (is the HTML tag encoded?).